# Direct2D Debug - An interface [x] was created but not released

Tags: directx, direct2d, directx-10

I have the Direct2D debug layer turned on. When my application exits, I get the following output:

D2D DEBUG ERROR - An interface [x] was created but not released. Use 'dps x' to view its allocation stack.

Where x is an address.

What is dps and how can I discover what interface is not being released, and view its allocation stack?

Thanks.

Comment: `dps` is a `WinDbg` command, if you're not familiar with it and if your code is not massive it's probably going to be quicker to just eyeball it to make sure you release every interface correctly. Using a wrapper (like `ComPtr` in Win8 or similar) around the interface pointers can help enormously to keep things clean.

Comment: ok i tried it in windbg, for some cases this is helpful but for some memory locations it just returns addresses as shown below, no allocation source code.. 00000000`087cf8f8  4210a533`19f2523d